# Remove part of a string which matches a RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string made up of a page title and a page URL, separated by " - ". I would like to return a string which contains everything exept the parameters in the URL.

**Input**
`This is a page title with a - and a ? - http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder/numbers134/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=a_source&utm_campaign=a_campaign_name`

**Desired Output**
`This is a page title with a - and a ? - http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder/numbers134/`

**What I have tried**

- I have tried .split() but because it is possible for the page title to have a "?" in it, this doesn't work.
- x.replace(x.match(/http:[a-z/.0-9-]*(?.+)$/),"") where x is the string. This feels like it should have worked. I'm not sure if it is possible to use a capture group like this?

So far I have a regex to match the part I want removed: http:[a-z/.0-9-]*(?.+)$

I'm not sure how to turn that around and return the string minus that part.

**Points**

1. Page tile and URL separated by " - "
2. Page title may contain "-" or "?"
3. URL may contain parameters
4. The solution should work for any combination of 1. or 2. being present or not for any page title and URL.
5. The URL will always be http (Don't ask)

Comment: Try `^.*?https?:\/\/[^\n?]+` https://regex101.com/r/BHGfHd/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird long live https

Answer (score 0):

If you can control what the separator is then do that. make it less predictable and unique.

that way you can split by the new split character(s) and then pass the rest of string to the [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
let SEPARATOR = '^^^';
let input = 'This is a page title with a - and a ? ^^^ http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder/numbers134/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=a_source&utm_campaign=a_campaign_name'

let url = new URL(input.substring(input.indexOf(SEPARATOR) + SEPARATOR.length));
// or
let url = new URL(input.split(SEPARATOR)[1])
console.log(url.origin + url.pathname)
// logs http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder/numbers134/
```

this way you also get for free the url validation logic

Answer (score 0):

Could you not achieve it using `lastIndexOf` and `substring` like this?

```js
var url = 'This is a page title with a - and a ? - http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder/numbers134/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=a_source&utm_campaign=a_campaign_name';

var output = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('?'));
console.log(output);
```